# NAnt and System.Data.Entity.dll

Tags: nant

I am new to NAnt and trying to set up a build file to build a few .Net 4.0 projects and run some NUnit tests. One of the projects contains an EF4.0 Data Model and context and I am running into an issue that even though the System.Data.Entity.dll reference is being included in the NAnt config, none of the System.Data classes contained in it are being found by the build (System.Data.EntityClient, System.Data.Objects, etc).  I am using NAnt 0.91 Alpha 2.  Anyone else run into this or have any idea how to get around it?  Build file below.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="ClinicalModel">
    <property name="src.dir" value="" />
    <property name="output.dir" value="bin/debug" />
    <property name="entitysrc" value="..\Entities" />
    <property name="debug" value="true" overwrite="false" />
    <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-4.0" />
    <property name="framework-get-assembly-directory" value="${framework::get-assembly-directory('net-4.0')}" />
    <property name="dotNetReferenceAssemblyPath" value="${framework-get-assembly-directory}\" />
    <target name="clean" description="clean up already built files">
        <delete file="${output.dir}/Entities.dll" failonerror="false" />
        <delete file="${output.dir}/Model.dll" failonerror="false" />
    </target>
    <target name="build_entities" description="build entities">
        <csc target="library" output="${output.dir}\Entities.dll" debug="${debug}">
            <sources basedir="${entitysrc}">
                <include name="**/*.cs" />
            </sources>
        </csc>
    </target>
    <target name="build" depends="build_entities" description="build model">
        <csc target="library" output="${output.dir}\Model.dll" debug="${debug}">
            <sources>
                <include name="**\*.cs" />
            </sources>
            <references basedir="${output.dir}">
                <include name="**\*.dll" />
            </references>
        </csc>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question but I'm interested to know why you are actually doing the building with NAnt.  I've always used NAnt to do numerous things (Build, FxCop, NUnit, move built files around etc) but for the actually building, I run the appropriate version of msbuild on the solution file.  It seemed too painful to have nice sln and csproj files but then to ignore them and basically have to reproduce them in NAnt script.  Am I missing something?  I can post sample code if you want to go this route.

Comment: We are trying to integrate with Atlassian Bamboo, which doesn't seem to support MSBuild very well.  I initially tried to use the msbuild extension for NAnt (NAntContrib), but had some other breaks in that due to some T4 templates not being properly handled.  Additionally, we are really only trying to test our data layer this way, and the solution contains web projects and web service projects that do not need to be built for the unit testing, so we are only really interested in 4 of 11 projects in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the solution you are looking for but I would recommend letting msbuild do the actual build work.  Since you don't want to build the entire solution you would end up making 4 calls (one for each project you want to build) to msbuild.  Here is a snippet from my root build script:

```
    <property name="common.msbuild2010" value="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe" />
    <property name="common.buildType" value="Debug" />

    ...

<setenv>
   <variable name="DevEnvDir" value="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\"/>
</setenv>

    <exec program="${common.msbuild2010}" commandline="&quot;${local.someCsProjName}&quot; /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=${common.buildType}" />
```

Comment: Using this method of loading msbuild (as opposed to the NAntContrib) worked.  So this seems to have solved it, thanks.